# Python unittests one by one works well but not together under Flask

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I've a test file containing some unittests. All of them looks like:

```
def test_something_222(self):
    with app.test_client() as c:
        response = c.get(URL)
        assert response.status_code == some_value
```

. When I run them one by one, everything works well, however using **python -m unittest** results error.

What can be the reason for it, and how can I prevent?

Thanks.

Comment: To be honest I have never encountered error `error`.

Comment: I just noticed that one my tests overwrote an environment variable, and that caused the error... .